# Embed fonts onto a page and I am not getting the results

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to embed fonts onto a page - I placed the 'ttf' files on the server and I am not getting the results - any help would be appreciated.... 
My JS fiddle link here:
http://jsfiddle.net/tanujasahoo111/8yFsu/

### HTML

```
<body>
<p class="name">
Academy Engraved LET - The quick brown Fox jumped over the lazy dog. 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
</p>
</body>
```

### css

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Academy Engraved LET"; 
src: url("http://www.fontyukle.net/en/Academy+Engraved+LET.ttf");
}
.name {
font-size: 70px;
font-family: "Academy Engraved LET";
}
```

Comment: Tell us what you've found during debugging? Have you checked the console? Did you try different fonts, different file formats, etc. etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first download the font from your given [site](http://www.fontyukle.net/en/Academy+Engraved+LET.ttf)
After that upload .ttf file to this [site](http://everythingfonts.com/font-face) and download font faces.

you will have diff formats like .eot, .woff, .svg, etc

your CSS will be like this :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AcademyEngravedLETRegular';
    src: url('academy_engraved_let.eot');
    src: url('academy_engraved_let.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('academy_engraved_let.woff') format('woff'),
         url('academy_engraved_let.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('academy_engraved_let.svg#AcademyEngravedLETRegular') format('svg');
}
.name {
font-size: 70px;
font-family: "AcademyEngravedLETRegular";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your browser's error console, it tells you what the problem is and how to fix it:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.fontyukle.net/en/Academy+Engraved+LET.ttf. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Warning like `“Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type ...“` in your web browser console?

When a font is downloaded from a web server that sets an unexpected MIME type for fonts.

Update the configuration for your web server with the following MIME type per font file extension:

```
.ttf — font/truetype
.otf — font/opentype
.eot — application/vnd.ms-fontobject
.woff — application/x-font-woff
```

If you are using Apache configuration, you may include the AddType directive for each font type:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
AddType font/opentype otf
AddType font/truetype ttf
AddType application/x-font-woff woff
```

With a specific MIME type configured per font, and not the generic application/octet-stream MIME type, you should no longer see a warning in your web browser console.

This configuration — while effective for cleaning up your console — does not include the technically correct MIME type for fonts like OTF, TTF, and WOFF. For these font types, an official MIME type has not (yet) been approved. An official type for WOFF — application/font-woff — has been requested.

[Source](http://www.jbarker.com/blog/2011/resource-interpreted-font-transferred-mime-type)